Making sense of positive and negative systems for eyeglass prescriptions
Let's say we have a pair of single vision eyeglasses and we're going to convert the "plus" system to the "minus" system.
That involves 3 steps:

Add the Sph and Cyl to get a new Sph.
Invert the sign on the Cyl.
Add 90 to the axis if less than 90, subtract 90 if more.

Plus system
           Sph     Cyl   Axis
    OD   -8.25   +1.50    159 
    OS   -8.50   +2.00      5

Minus system
           Sph     Cyl   Axis
    OD   -6.75   -1.50     69 
    OS   -6.50   -2.00     95

Everyone in the optics world will just tell you to add the plus-system Sph+Cyl and that's the new Sph.  Which makes me confused.  Adding Spherical and Cylindrical is like saying you have a 1kg ball on a 7cm string, and we're going to convert it to another system by adding the 1 and 7 to get a 8 kg ball.  If we want to correct just the spherical part of someone's vision, do we make an OD spherical lens at -8.25 or -6.75 diopters?
What sense does adding Cyl and Sph make other than if these steps are repeated, they reciprocate?


Adding spherical power and cylindrical power isn't like adding apples and oranges (or mass and length)!

          Sph     Cyl   Axis
   OD   -6.75   -1.50     69    (The 'minus' system)


This system specifies “Cyl” nonpositively. The above prescription says that the right eye's prescribed correction along the axis 69° is $-6.75,$ whereas its prescribed correction along the other principal meridian (i.e., the perpendicular axis 159°) is $$-6.75-1.50 = -8.25.$$

          Sph     Cyl   Axis
   OD   -8.25   +1.50    159    (The 'plus' system)


I neither work in optometry nor have heard of the "plus" system, but evidently this system specifies “Cyl” nonnegatively. This second prescription says exactly the same thing as the previous prescription (unsurprisingly, since they are by design mathematically equivalent): the right eye's prescribed correction along the axis 159° is $-8.25,$ whereas its prescribed correction along the perpendicular meridian 69° (i.e., 159°+90° modulo 180°) is $$-8.25+1.50 = -6.75.$$

In both systems, “Sph” states the correction along the specified axis while to this, “Cyl” states the greatest amount of adjustment, which is along the perpendicular axis.

Note that the names “Plus system” and “Minus system” are not referring to the sign of the “Sph” specifications or the eyeglass lenses’ concavity/convexity or the patient's myopia/hyperopia.

You might have heard of optometrists computing a lens's “spherical equivalent” by taking the sum of “Sph” and half of “Cyl” (in the above prescriptions, this equals $-7.50).$ This is just the average of the powers along the lens's two principal axes, which is basically the lens's mean power along all its axes!


